# To opt for interest only home loan and save for next property down payment or keep paying P&I to reduce debt AND borrow more for next property

Tags: mortgage, savings, australia, home-loan

I currently own an investment property which I bought to live in (lived in for couple of years) and now has rented out as I moved (renting) in a better area for kids school.

I am comfortably managing to pay P&I on my current investment loan and trying to save as much for 20% deposit to buy home for living in( say in next 3 years). 
My question is: Should I switch to interest only loan for the duration i am saving deposit to buy my home? or should I continue P&I investment loan so that I will have equity, less debt (which will allow to comfortably borrow for the next home), breaking down the numbers gets to below scenario:

P&I: will be paying $300 out of MY pocket (rest will be from rental income) each month + 5K yearly for management/council etc. expenses. So total spending around 9K each year.

Interest only: saving $400 each month(difference between IO monthly repayment and the rental income I receive) + 5K yearly for management/council etc. expenses.

Will be receiving tax deduction on loan interest and all other expenses.

Any advise will be appreciated, this is to weight all options before I speak to financial adviser so that i know what advise I am getting/pros and cons.

I am typically a conservative old school who always want to have less debt, also geography is Australia (for the context).Currently i own 25% of the home.

Comment: "P&I: will be paying $300 out of pocket each month".  The way you wrote it seems like your mortgage payment is only $300/month.  And "Interest only: saving $400 each month" looks like the bank is paying you to borrow money.

Comment: $300 out of my pocket, rest is coming from the rental income, also saving $400 is based on the calculation i did for IO repayment and monthly rental income which leaves me with +$400 each month.

Comment: Please edit the answer to say that.

Comment: thanks for suggesting, i have edited to include these details

Comment: Anyway, are there transaction costs for changing to an Interest only loan?  As for the total **debt** amount of debt, it seems to me that you're robbing Peter to pay Paul, since you'd still have to eventually pay back the loan on the current house.  If you continue paying principal on the current house, and therefore accumulating more equity in it, can you then borrow against that equity to help buy the new house?  (That's what people in the US do; don't know if it's legal in Aus.)

Comment: Current fixed term is ending soon and there will be no transaction costs for opting interest only (definitely higher interest rate compare to P&I). In AUS one can use existing equity to buy new house. Though my concern remains that if its bad idea to switch to IO to save for next home(robbing Peter to pay Paul :))? or be conservative and keep P&I which may increase the time period to save for next home.

Comment: All I can say is that a **lot** of people in the US who had IO loans were ruined when the housing bubble popped 12 years ago.

Comment: @RonJohn ditto in the UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you can claim a tax deduction for the mortgage interest on the investment property but not on the mortgage interest on a future house you plan to live in, you are better off paying Interest Only on the investment property so that you can save as much as posible for your main residence.

The more you can save means the less you need to borrow for the new house. Once you have you new main residence you shoul make that P&I and pay it off as soon as possible. Once you have fully paid off your main residence then you could start paying P&I on your investment property if it gets you a lower interest rate.

Comment: Is there a mortgage interest tax deduction in the UK?

Comment: @Victor, "you are better off paying Interest Only on the investment property so that you can save as much as possible for your main residence" this is what i have been thinking.. thank you.

Comment: @RonJohn - I don't know I am in Australia!

Comment: @Victor I don't know why I wrote "UK".  Is there a mortgage interest tax deduction in Aus?

Comment: @RonJohn - as I wrote in my answer, in Australia there is a tax deduction for the mortgage interest on the investment property but not on the mortgage interest on your main residence. The basic rule is, if you are not earning (or attempting to earn) an income from the property, then the interest and other expenses are not tax-deductible.

Comment: @Victor that's the exact opposite of how it works in the US.  :)

Comment: @RonJohn - so you are saying that in the US you cannot claim a tax deduction for the interest incurred for an investment property? I find that hard to believe since it is earning money and you should be able to claim any expenses incurred in earning that income against it. The reason you cannot claim a deduction in Australia for the interest against your main residence is because when you sell your main residence you get an exemption from paying any capital gains (which is not the case in the US).

Comment: @Victor hmm.  I confused the rules for "investment property" with those of "second home".  Note though, that the US **does** have **both** CG exclusion for your primary residence **and** mortgage interest deduction.

Answer (score 1):

The main disadvantage of an interest only (IO) loan is that it typically has a higher interest rate than principal plus interest (PI) loans. If the rates were identical, then for a *disciplined* person it would be better to choose the IO loan, because then you can decide if and when it makes the most sense to start paying down the loan. For example, you might choose to do something more lucrative with the money like invest it at a higher return, or pay down a higher interest loan first. Similarly, when given the option of a 15 year or 30 year loan at identical rates, you should choose the 30 year loan for the same reason. If it makes sense you can make larger payments to make a 30 year loan act like a 15 year loan (or lower!), but in months where you'd rather have the extra money for something else you don't have to make the larger payment. So it really boils down to if you believe you can get a better return on your money.

Note, I emphasized a *disciplined* person because absent of that quality an IO loan may never get paid off, and could end up causing regret down the road. Having a PI loan forces some level of discipline upon you, at the cost of less control over your money.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, as you suggested extra $$ from having IO would be help in disciplined approach toward my plan to buy residence property sooner .